# Are there any differences between Okami and Okami HD apart from the graphics?

Tags: version-differences, okami, okami-hd

Okami is now reborn in High Definition for PS3. The graphics are obviously better, sharper and yet preserves the gist of the original game, however I can swear some of the texts have changed as well.

My PS2 console is no longer available to me so I can't test it myself, but does anyone know whether there are any changes to the game (aside from graphics) or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only does it seem [you can no longer acquire demon fangs via loading screens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/186552/88), but also via the reflector sub-weapon attack. So far this is all I can find.

Comment: I vaguely remember doing something in loading screens, but wasn't sure of this. Thanks for reminding me and you're totally right! Wonder why they ditched that cool feature. :/

Comment: I believe the "loading screens" feature was ditched mainly because loading take a shorter while on this while, most of the time it wont even get to the right side of the screen before continuing...

Comment: Can you clarify what was changed about the reflector sub-weapon attack?

Answer (score 5):

One more change: both the Wii version and the HD PS3 version do not have the original song from the closing credits ("Reset" by Ayaka Hirahara). It was removed for some [pretty](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=18469) [stupid](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/clover-removed-from-okami-wii-credits) reasons.

Comment: Good catch, I would never have noticed that!

Comment: According to the [Okami Wiki](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Ckami#HD_version), the HD PS3 port actually included the original PS2 end credits theme that was cut from the Wii release.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It didn't when I played it...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only changes are really the graphics and the added trophy and move support. Even reviewers who played the game on PS2 haven't mentioned any changes apart from that (e.g. [Eurogamer Review](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-10-30-okami-hd-review)).

Comment: Thanks, I read this exact review before posting here actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

Combining all of the previous answers into a single post...

- The [paw-print loading screen mini-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186532/what-happened-to-the-loading-screen-game/186552#186552) was removed (presumably due to faster load times)
- The original PS2 closing credits theme ["Reset"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM6X76YMrF4) was restored (Preciously excluded from Wii release [for legal reasons](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/clover-removed-from-okami-wii-credits))
- [Collectable trophies were added](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Ckami_HD%27s_achievements)
- Support for the PlayStation Move controller
- Improved graphics and 1080p widescreen support

Comment: @Gnemlock Good point. I have converted the answer to a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the food bag stuff was changed:
PS2 had monkey eating meat while the PS3 has monkeys eating seed.

There are a few little peculiarities like this. But overall its a good port, having played the Wii version then the PS2 version then the PS3 version, the PS2 version has remained the best version since I played it.

The segment which requires you to draw on a character on a blank page is only fully realised on the PS2 version where your character shows up in the credits.

And the rice paper filter is there but it is less noticeable because of the resolution boost.The progressive scan also makes the colours much more vivid. These two issues combined create a much different experience from the original.

If you want the best experience then the original PS2 version with GSM or PCSX2 is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For the Nintendo Switch version, you can turn on the load screen mini game. You have to do it from the menu of options (- button).