# What happened to the Loading Screen game?

Tags: okami, okami-hd

In Okami, there used to be a mini-game in the loading screen, that if you pressed a particular button when a paw-print appeared, and you got all of them in a row, it would show a Demon Fang instead of Issun:

[image]

Is this game still in Okami HD? I've tried mashing every button (except Select and Start) to no avail.

Also, I can't quite remember, but did this actually give you a Demon Fang in the original game?

EDIT: I have found [this article in the wiki](http://okami.wikia.com/wiki/Loading_screen_games), but as it states it needs to be completely rewritten, so I wanted to verify it.

Comment: which version, only the PS2 had it IIRC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was sure the question had already been asked on this site but I can't find it.

That mini-game has been removed, as the loading screens are a lot faster on a PS3 and most of the time there wouldn't be enough time to finish the game if it existed.

It did give fangs in the original PS2 version. The pictured mini-game gave you a fang every time you successfully pressed the X button in sync with the paw prints appearing, while a different loading screen gave you one if you pressed it enough times before it disappeared.

Comment: Do you remember whether or not the minigame actually did reward a Demon Fang? Or was it just for show?

Comment: @Ben: In the original PS2 version? It did, that's how I got most of my fangs. Mainly the other loading screen though, if it lasted enough.